# Update table using query result

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am attempting to add the result of my query into the column of an existing table.
Thus far, the query below calculates the `CAR_PRICE` and displays the value. However, I want to add this value to the `CAR_PAYMENT_TBL` in the car_price column.

The create table commands below show the relevant table and the relationships between them. Is it possible to update the `CAR_PRICE` value in the `CAR_PAYMENT_TBL`?

```
SELECT C.TICKET_NO, 
            C.REG_ID,
            C.BOOKING_ID,
            (R.END_DATE-R.START_DATE) AS DAYS_STAYED,
            (R.END_DATE-R.START_DATE)*5 AS CAR_PRICE
            FROM CAR_TBL C
            LEFT JOIN
            ROOM_TBL R
            ON C.BOOKING_ID = R.BOOKING_ID;
```

TABLE SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL
(
    TICKET_NO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CAR_PRICE NUMERIC(5,2) 
);

CREATE TABLE CAR_TBL
(
    REG_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TICKET_NO INT NOT NULL references CAR_PAYMENT_TBL(TICKET_NO),
    BOOKING_ID INT NOT NULL references BOOKING_TBL(BOOKING_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ROOM_TBL
(  
    STAY_NO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ROOM_NO VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL references ROOM_DETAILS_TBL(ROOM_NO),
    START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    END_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    BOOKING_ID INT NOT NULL references BOOKING_TBL(BOOKING_ID)
);
```

Comment: please consider using a join to write your update ( a subquery like this must only return ONE row, since you are using &ticket_no this should be ok, Im just sayin). Next, you would need to write `SET CAR_PRICE = ( SELECT [your earlier statement ] );`

Comment: How are room_tbl and car_payment_tbl related?

Comment: you are missing some joins...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SCHEMA ADDED

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reference other tables in an UPDATE statement in Oracle - use a subquery or a MERGE statement:

```
  UPDATE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL
  SET CAR_PRICE =
  (select (ROOM_TBL.END_DATE - ROOM_TBL.START_DATE)*5 from room_tbl where ... )
  WHERE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL.TICKET_NO = &TICKET_NO;
```

You'll also have to provide a sensible WHERE clause for the subquery (assuing &TICKET_NO is really a bind variable and not your join condition for the two tables).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all the records of `CAR_PAYMENT_TBL` based on the values of `ROOM_TBL`
then

```
UPDATE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL
SET CAR_PRICE = (select (ROOM_TBL.END_DATE – ROOM_TBL.START_DATE)*5
FROM ROOM_TBL WHERE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL.TICKET_NO = ROOM_TBL.TICKET_NO)
```

If you want to update only specific record of `CAR_PAYMENT_TBL` then

```
UPDATE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL
SET CAR_PRICE = (select (ROOM_TBL.END_DATE – ROOM_TBL.START_DATE)*5
FROM ROOM_TBL WHERE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL.TICKET_NO = ROOM_TBL.TICKET_NO)
where CAR_PAYMENT_TBL = &ticket_num;
```

Comment: These queries don't work due the relationships between the tables involved. I have provided the schema of the relevant tables

Comment: I have made an edit to my post. Is there any other way of doing this update taking into consideration the schema?